# Node/WebpackDevServer/react-scripts, remove "To create a production build, use npm run build" message on start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I have an issue when I run `yarn start` on my javascript/react application which uses webpack and WebpackDevServer. On successful compilation it shows this familiar message;

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view {project name} in the browser.

  http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

The issue is that `npm run build` is not the command that must be used to produce a production build so this actually giving wrong instruction, is there any way to remove or customize this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is printed because my start script uses `createCompiler` in react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils.js, in here the `printInstructions` function prints this on successful compile, see [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils.js#L97-L100). The only possible configuration is to set `useYarn` to true which just replaces the command with `yarn build`. So I can either use a different package or fork it, neither of which ideal.

The slightly hacky workaround for this was to override console.log to catch this message and replace it with the desired message, like below.

```
const originalConsoleLog = console.log
console.log = (args) => {
    if (typeof args === 'string' && args.indexOf("To create a production build, use ") !== -1) {
        let stringToReplace = `use ${chalk.cyan(`${useYarn ? 'yarn' : 'npm run'} build`)}`
        args = args.replace(stringToReplace, {your instructions string here})
        console.log = originalConsoleLog
    }
    args ? originalConsoleLog(args) : originalConsoleLog()
}
```

Where `useYarn` is the same `useYarn` passed to `react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils`'s `createCompiler`. On the catch, `console.log` is once again replaced with the original.

Answer (score -1):

This is a recommendation not a requirment for production build.

It looks like you had a successfull compilation.

Comment: It's not a recommendation, it's explicitly telling the customer to use npm run build for a production build, if they do that it fails. This also doesn't answer my question

Comment: I get it that it does not answer the question. i thought i mentioned that in my post. sorry.